# SQL Server 2008 Filestream File Size Contribution

Tags: sql-server, filestream, sql-server-2008-express

Just a question regarding the Filestream in SQL Server 2008: does the size of the file itself contribute to the total size of the database, or because the Filestream stores in the file in the NTFS, and stores the relative path in the database (this is what I believe is what is happening with Filestream), only the string length of filepath matters?

I know that the max `VARBINARY` size doesn't matter only the size of the NTFS. I am asking this in regards to SQL Server Express with a 10gb size limit. Let's assume you are going to store a 500mb file does the 500mb file eat up 500 mb of the max size available to the Express version, or only the size of the file path being stored?

Thanks All

Sorry if the question is a bit round about :/

Comment: I guess you mean the **Express** version. There is no "Free" version of SQL-Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it does not count towards the size
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/06/03/sql-server-express-size-limit-filestream-excepted.aspx

Comment: Awesome Thank You :) Been looking for a post about that :)

Comment: My pleasure, had the same question a while back and kept the link for reference

Comment: You answered the question to quickly and now I have to wait to accept :( :P